# Sqlite exception in create table sentense

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a `database` with two tables. lately, i inserted a new row(`key_today`)and I get the following `sqlite` `exception` :

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "text": syntax error: create table tasks (_id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null,location text not null, body text not null ,  goaldate text not null ,  absolutedate text not null ,  currentdate text not null ,  prio text not null,  done text not null,  category text not null,  timespent text not null,  pososto text not null,  father text not null,  check text not null );
```

I have changed the methods in order to include the new row but i really cannot find what im doing wrong.

here is my code, thank you in advance

```
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_FATHER="father";//father's id
public static final String KEY_location = "location";
public static final String KEY_GOAL_DATE = "goaldate";
public static final String KEY_ABSOLUTE_DATE = "absolutedate";
public static final String KEY_DATE_CURRENT = "currentdate";
public static final String KEY_PRIO= "prio";
public static final String KEY_DONE = "done";
public static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";
public static final String KEY_TIME_SPEND = "timespent";
public static final String KEY_POSOSTO = "pososto";
public static final String KEY_TODAY= "check";

public static final String KEY_STITLE = "atitle";
public static final String KEY_ROID = "_id"; 
public static final String KEY_SCOLOR = "color";


private static final String TAG = "ListDatabase";
/**
 * @uml.property  name="mDbHelper"
 * @uml.associationEnd  
 */
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

/**
 * Creating   database tables
 */
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table tasks (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "

    + "title text not null,"
    +"location text not null, " 
    + "body text not null , "
    +" goaldate text not null , "
    +" absolutedate text not null , "
    +" currentdate text not null , "
    +" prio text not null, "
    +" done text not null, "
    +" category text not null, "
    +" timespent text not null, "
    +" pososto text not null, "
    +" father text not null, " 
    +" check text not null );";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Check` is [a reserved word in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html); try renaming that column or putting it in (escaped) double quotes in your SQL statement.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what's causing the problem:

```
... check text not null)
    ^^^^^
```

[`check`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) is a keyword in SQLite (and SQL in general).

Put it in double quotes like this to avoid such problems:

```
... "check" text not null)
```